# sql split column in columns by delimiter

Tags: sql, split, delimiter

I have a SQL table in a SQL database in Azure with the column id which has entries in the form AAA_1, AAA_2, BBB_1, BBB_2.... I would like to split this column in two columns by the delimiter _ like this:

| id | … |
| --- | --- |
| AAA_1 | … |
| AAA_2 | … |
| BBB_2 | … |

| id1 | id2 | … |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 | … |
| AAA | 2 | … |
| BBB | 2 | … |

The split function mainly splits a specific string and not a column.

Comment: String functions are product-specific, as the *`sql` tag* description recommends, you should [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `SPLIT_PART()` to separate the column based on delimiter `"_"`

```
SELECT
  id,
  SPLIT_PART(id, '_', 1) AS id1,
  SPLIT_PART(id, '_', 2) AS id2
FROM your_table_name;
```

- SPLIT_PART() takes 3 args(column you want to split (id) + delimiter ('_') + position of the substring)

**update**
this solution is supported by a wide range of SQL databases such as PostgreSQL/MySQL/SQLite...

If you are working with SQL Server you can try `PARSENAME()`

```
SELECT
  id,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(id, '_', '.'), 2) AS id1,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(id, '_', '.'), 1) AS id2
FROM your_table_name;
```

- `REPLACE()` will replace `_` with `.` so that `PARSENAME()` can split the string

Ps. check documentations for your DB to see if `SPLIT_PART()` is supported and equivalent functions

Comment: You'd better annotate which DBMS support this solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am using SQL database in Azure and  received the following error: Failed to execute query. Error: 'SPLIT_PART' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Azure provides a managed database service called Azure SQL Database -- supports T-SQL language for SQL queries -- it supports `PARSENAME()`

Comment: But the second version with parsing worked, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want your query works against multiple DB vendors try to use ANSI Standard (most common naming conventions that should be respected by all the vendors / this is not always the case but here that can not be the case)

You have to introduce the new column, by splitting (parsing) id into two columns:

```
with test as(
    select  'id_1' complex_id,
            'some data from other cols' other_cols
    union all
    select  'id_2' complex_id,
            'some data from other cols' other_cols
)
select  complex_id,
        substring(complex_id, 1, position('_' in complex_id) - 1)   text_part_of_id,
        substring(complex_id, position('_' in complex_id) + 1)      int_part_of_id
from    test;

complex_id|text_part_of_id|substring|
----------+---------------+---------+
id_1      |id             |1        |
id_2      |id             |2        |
```

About the differences between the vendors, for example: in Oracle position() is called instr() (https://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-postgresql/instr)

Or you could use SPLIT_PART function if you are using PostreSQL, or you can try something fancy as given below (https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/split_part-function.php)

This is a nice article about string splitting in SQL: [https://www.databasestar.com/sql-split-string/#:~:text=You%20can%20split%20a%20string,translate%20this%20into%20separate%20rows](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-split-string/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20split%20a%20string,translate%20this%20into%20separate%20rows).